# How to push a new Screen when document is loaded in BrowserField?

Tags: blackberry

In my application I have a log in Screen. When the user enter the correct user name and password I have to collect the information from the website and navigate to main Screen.

I tried following code. But this code is not working. How to achieve it?

```java
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen {
    public MyScreen() {
        BrowserFieldConfig myBrowserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
        myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,
        BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
        BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField(myBrowserFieldConfig);

        BrowserFieldListener list = new BrowserFieldListener() {
            public void documentLoaded(BrowserField browserField, Document document) throws Exception {
                String url = document.getBaseURI();
                String val = "http://demo.....";
                //i am checking the correct url and i will navigate to main screen
                if (url.equals(new String(val))) {
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new Main());//here i got IllegalStateException ..
                }
                System.out.println(" Login  URL " + url);
                //super.documentLoaded(browserField, document);
            }
        };

        browserField.addListener(list);
        add(browserField);
        String URL = "http://demo.....";
        if (DeviceInfo.isSimulator()) {
            URL = URL + ";deviceSide=true";
        }
        browserField.requestContent(URL);
    }
}
```

Comment: `this is not working.` - what is going wrong with your code? Write down your experience when you run this code. You can set a break point on the first line of `documentLoaded` method for debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your commend. i got the IllegalArgumentException

Comment: how can i push to new screen?

Comment: IllegalArgumentException - where (on which line) you got this?

Comment: i got IllegalStateException in the UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new Main());   line...

Comment: The accepted answer will help to get rid of IllegalStateException, but you said on your question, `When the user enter the correct user name and password I have to collect the information from the website and navigate to main Screen`. But actually you are switching the screen when requested page just loaded. So, I think you need to update your question too.

Comment: this just sample Rupak... i am trouble to navigate the page from theBrowserField now i can implement it in my app.... thanks for your replay..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in place of

```
  UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new Main());
```

use

```
 UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new Main());
                    }
                });
```

you need to do it under ui Thread.
Check it.